# Forget All Accounts Password of Ubuntu Including root

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I am new to Ubuntu and unfortunately after creating account and changing root passwords I forgot all passwords. Now I don't want to reinstall
Ubuntu. I just want a way so that I can reset my root password. Does anyone know how to get through with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this probably isn't a stackoverflow question. It probably belongs here: https://serverfault.com/

But to answer your question, use the grub boot menu to start in recovery mode. You will have a root session where you can run 'passwd' on root (bad idea unless you normally use a root password in Ubuntu) or for any local user.

This all assumes you have local or lights-out console access.